# JS reduce: TypeError: Cannot create property at Array.reduce

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
let keys = ['a','b','c'];
let vals = ['1','b','h'];
const my_obj = keys.reduce(function(acc,key,i) {
return acc[key]=vals[i];
},{});

logger.log(my_obj);
```

I would like `my_obj` to be `{a:1,b:b,c:h}`.

I'm getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot create property 'b' on string '1'

at Array.reduce
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(keys.map((val,i)=>[val,vals[i]]))`

Comment: You need to return the accumulator itself.

Comment: `return acc[key]=vals[i];` - Replace `return` with `console.log()` and check the output

Comment: the accumulator is getting corrupted because you are not returning the accumulator at the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use reduce method then its fine, but you will have to return the accumulator to make it work.

```js
let keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let vals = ['1', 'b', 'h'];
const my_obj = keys.reduce(function(acc, key, i) {
  acc[key] = vals[i];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(my_obj);
```

But I will suggest to use the simple for loop, because of just the simplicity of problem

```js
let keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let vals = ['1', 'b', 'h'];
let my_obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
  my_obj[keys[i]] = vals[i];

console.log(my_obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return object as acc.
In your code you are returning the assigned value

```js
let keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let vals = ['1', 'b', 'h'];
const my_obj = keys.reduce(function(acc, key, i) {
  acc[key] = vals[i];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(my_obj);
```

Comment: changed the return statement

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

`return acc[key]=vals[i];` actually return the value of `vals[i]` ==> you finally get `h` only on https://playcode.io/ environment.

Updated: in your environment, you got that error because:

- after first run of `keys.reduce` your next `acc` will be `"1"` (return `acc[key]= vals[0]}`  equal return `vals[0]` which is `"1"`)
- Now you come to second round of `keys.reduce`, your acc is `"1"` then you set  `acc[key]= vals[1]}` equal `"1"[b] = vals[1]`   ==> you got that error

Try this:

```js
let keys = ['a','b','c'];
let vals = ['1','b','h'];

const my_obj = keys.reduce(function(acc,key,i) {
// return new expanded acc
return ({...acc, [key]: vals[i]})
},{});

console.log(my_obj);
```

Comment: Thanks Tony , I'm learning a lot from this. Very cool!

Comment: I am glad it helped.